# PySpark UDF: a fir transform example

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, term-document-matrix

I am really new to PySpark and am trying to translate some python code into pyspark.
I start with a panda, convert to a document - term matrix and then apply PCA.

The UDF:

```
    class MultiLabelCounter():
        def __init__(self, classes=None):
            self.classes_ = classes

        def fit(self,y):
            self.classes_ = 
    sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)))
            self.mapping = dict(zip(self.classes_,
                                         
    range(len(self.classes_))))
            return self

    def transform(self,y):
        yt = []
        for labels in y:
            data = [0]*len(self.classes_)
            for label in labels:
                data[self.mapping[label]] +=1
            yt.append(data)
        return yt

    def fit_transform(self,y):
        return self.fit(y).transform(y)
```

```
    mlb = MultiLabelCounter()
```

```
    df_grouped = 
    df_grouped.withColumnRenamed("collect_list(full)","full")

    udf_mlb = udf(lambda x: mlb.fit_transform(x),IntegerType())

    mlb_fitted = df_grouped.withColumn('full',udf_mlb(col("full")))
```

I am of course getting NULL results.

I am using spark 2.4.4 version.

## EDIT

Adding sample input and output as per request

Input:

```
|id|val|
|--|---|
|1|[hello,world]|
|2|[goodbye, world]|
|3|[hello,hello]|
```

Output:

```
|id|hello|goodbye|world|
|--|-----|-------|-----|
|1|1|0|1|
|2|0|1|1|
|3|2|0|0|
```

Comment: Can you share some sample input and output datasets?

Comment: can that method be a function outside the class? That would make things easier.

Comment: @LuizViola yes I am sure they can be moved outside the class

Comment: @DKNY I have added this

Comment: Looking at input and output it seems the implementation of one hot encode in PySpark, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @LuizViola like onehotencode with but frequency counts instead of binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon input data shared, I tried replicating your output and it works. Please see below -

**Input Data**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1, ['hello', 'world']), (2, ['goodbye', 'world']), (3, ['hello', 'hello'])], schema=['id', 'vals'])

df.show()

+---+----------------+
| id|            vals|
+---+----------------+
|  1|  [hello, world]|
|  2|[goodbye, world]|
|  3|  [hello, hello]|
+---+----------------+
```

Now, using `explode` to create separate rows out of `vals` list items. Thereafter, using `pivot` and `count` will calculate the frequency. Finally, replacing `null` values with `0` using `fillna(0)`. See below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = df.select(['id', explode(col('vals'))]).groupBy("id").pivot("col").agg(count(col("col")))

df1.fillna(0).orderBy("id").show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+-------+-----+-----+
| id|goodbye|hello|world|
+---+-------+-----+-----+
|  1|      0|    1|    1|
|  2|      1|    0|    1|
|  3|      0|    2|    0|
+---+-------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you @DKNY a streamlined sloution that worked as needed :)